# TPLINK WN8200ND usb wifi not working

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb

i have an ubuntu version in a desktop pc, and i have an usb wifi adaptador brand TP-LINK WN8200ND with a chipset brand REALTEK rtl8192cu, and i can't make it work. I've tried everything, ndiswrapper, driver's linux and when i put 'lsusb' not recognize and when i put 'iwconfig' not appear 'wlan0'

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure you have the necessary prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git
```

Clone the updated driver with `git`:

```
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
```

Set it up as a DKMS module:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
```

Build and install the driver:

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.8
```

Refresh the module list:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Ensure the native (and broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:

```
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

Let's not take any chances. Instruct Ubuntu to load the new driver when it starts up.

```
echo 8192cu | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Reboot.

### You're done.

<sub>Thanks to [P. Varet](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) for this awesome fix.</sub>

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.