# Unable to install driver WN8200ND V2 (RTL8192EU)

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, adapter

i'am having troubles with this TPLINK Adapter, i can't use it... i tried EVERYTHING but still won't work I NEED HELP.

Model TPLink TL-WN8200ND(UN) V2

lshw (at usb port)

```
*-usb:1 NO RECLAMADO
                  descripción: Dispositivo USB genérico
                  producto: 802.11n NIC
                  fabricante: Realtek
                  id físico: 3
                  información del bus: usb@1:1.3
                  versión: 2.00
                  serie: 503EAA309137
                  capacidades: usb-2.10
                  configuración: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

lsusb:...

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:038f Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2357:0126  <<<<<(Look at this, i googled it, no answers.)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0458:0179 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 22b8:2e25 Motorola PCS 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

yeah, it's spanish

I tried to install in many ways, nothing works

My PC is a HP240(G5)

Works perfect in Windows(10)

Led's off in Ubuntu (like if it was disconnected) and it warms up slowly

**TRIES**

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340202

[TPLINK WN8200ND usb wifi not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364091/tplink-wn8200nd-usb-wifi-not-working)

Install other OS (Debian)

https://ubuntuperonista.blogspot.com.ar/2016/05/realtek-wifi-chipsets-ubuntu-instalar-driver-compilar-controlador.html (Ndiswrapper didn't work 'cause driver is only available at .exe, can't find .inf, TRIED TO EXTRACT FROM EXE ((V2)))

Official driver at Tplink page http://www.tp-link.com/au/download/TL-WN8200ND.html#Driver

Many things I remember confusingly, it's all

**Edit2**

I tried installing https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver , didn't work, tried blacklisting RTL8192CU, didn't work, tried unninstalling rtl8192cu driver(dkms), didn't work, *still without name* at lsusb (unrecognizable)

**Edit3**

> > wireless-info>https://paste.ubuntu.com/26531177/
> >
> > dkms-status>https://paste.ubuntu.com/26531194/

Comment: Use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1003112/edit) link to remove the drama. Instead, tell us about 'everything' you tried. A quick Search for "Ubuntu RTL8192EU" shows that your choice of adapter was perhaps unwise, but can work quite well with Ubuntu without great trauma.

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665 and copy the contents of the wireless-info.txt file and paste at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL.  Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `dkms status; ls ~/`  I have made some changes to rtl8192eu source code but I need to check some things out first.  The TP-Link Windows driver shows the 2357:0126 device as rtl8192eu

Answer (score 1):

I actually have success installing TP-Link TL-WN8200ND(UN) V2 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop (64-bit).

I modified the driver from https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver to add support for TL-WN8200ND V2 (By only adding 1 line precisely). I have forked the driver and you can install it by following this step in the terminal:

```
cd ~
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/agtbaskara/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
cd /usr/src/rtl8192eu-1.0/
sudo make clean
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -a 8192eu
```

And the reboot your PC, for my case it should be working.

**EDIT 1 : USE THIS https://github.com/luckynzm/tlwn8200nddriver**

**My modified driver actually very buggy, and disconnected the wifi after several minutes**

**EDIT 2 : There is another problem for me, after about an hour the device kick to a "Power Save" state randomly, I have solve it by changing these line:**

```
CONFIG_POWER_SAVING = y
```

**to**

```
CONFIG_POWER_SAVING = n
```

**in the Makefiles before installing the driver**

Comment: Hey dude! nice to see that someone cared about this device, i'll try this! i'd just login to thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
cd ~
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/luckynzm/tlwn8200nddriver
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
cd /usr/src/rtl8192eu-1.0/
sudo make clean
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -a 8192eu
```

worked for me after disabling secure boot don't know how to properly sine the module
if sum one can modify the solution to remove old rtl8192eu/1.0 installations and properly sine the module for secure boot these thread will b perfect i guess

removing old rtl8192eu/1.0 installations

```
sudo dkms status
```

will show the installed modules

```
sudo dkms remove -n rtl8192eu -v 1.0 --all
```

will remove old rtl8192eu/1.0 module from previous attempts

Answer (score 0):

**I solved it this way:**
**My Device:** (KDE Neon 5.20) **Linux version 5.4.0-58-generic** (buildd@lcy01-amd64-004) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17 **ubuntu1~20.04**)) **#64-Ubuntu**  
**Repo used:** https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver. Code used from the section Section: **Building and installing using DKMS**.

```
$ sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms;
$ git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver;
$ cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver;
$ sudo dkms add .;
$ sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0;
$ echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf;
$ echo -e "8192eu\n\nloop" | sudo tee /etc/modules;
$ echo "options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf;
$ sudo update-grub; sudo update-initramfs -u;
$ systemctl reboot -i;
```

I have wifi which is what I need