# Drivers for TP-LINK TL-WN8200ND v2

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kubuntu

I'm testing Ubuntu 18.04 with my current desktopand everything works correctly *except for the Wi-Fi adapter*. I'm using a TP-LINK TL-WN8200ND version 2.

As requested [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/44179), my `wireless-info` output is at [this pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PyFsVxk35W/).

I've tested Mint 19, Kubuntu and KDE neon, with similar results.

Is there an official driver that works out of the box?

Answer (score 7):

For newer kernels (>=5) you could use the driver from https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux

I tried with success from Ubuntu 19.04:beta (kernel 5.0.0-7-generic)

First, install kernel-headers, build-essentials, git, binutils and dkms packages.

```
sudo apt install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git binutils dkms
```

Finally, download the driver and install as **root**

```
sudo bash
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux/
./install_wifi.sh
```

Comment: It works for me with a TP-Link TL-WN8200ND on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: works for me too with a TP-Link TL-WN8200ND on Kali 2021.03

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 20.04 this should work for TL-WN8200ND.

Using the terminal, type the commands below:

```
sudo apt update;

sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms;

git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver;

cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver;

sudo dkms add .;

sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0;

echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8xxxu.conf;

echo -e "8192eu\n\nloop" | sudo tee /etc/modules;

echo "options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf;

sudo update-grub; sudo update-initramfs -u;

systemctl reboot -i;
```

Source:
https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

Adapter image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/luckynzm/tlwn8200nddriver.git
cd tlwn8200nddriver
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

This will take some time; please be patient.

Next, blacklist the built in driver that isn’t working:

```
sudo -i
echo “blacklist rtl8xxxu”  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Your wireless should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to make it work for the last couple of weeks, and finally I found a driver that works.

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4.15.0-46**. Check yours with

```
uname -a
```

### **What did work**

From https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340202

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu- 
linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make
sudo make install
reboot
```

It also says that if the kernel is updated do:
(so keep the directory)

```
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

### Testing connection

The first thing to notice is that the led is going green.
On the top right click on wifi symbol and the network must appear (my internal adapter and the USB adapter in my case). You can connect to a wifi network here.
You can also check your adapters with:

```
iwconfig
```

You can also check it with:

```
lshw -short
```

Unplug it and run the command again to see which one was the usb adapter.

You can also create a hostpot, ad-hoc or station mode network with the command:

```
nm-connection-editor
```

Just as in Ubuntu 16.04.

### **What didn't work for me**

I tried this drivers without success:

- git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes
- git clone https://github.com/dz0ny/rt8192cu.git --depth 1
- git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8192eu-linux-driver
- git clone https://github.com/luckynzm/tlwn8200nddriver.git
- git clone https://github.com/0xBADEAFFE/rt8192cu_dkms
- git clone https://github.com/agtbaskara/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git (I didn't try this one, found it after it worked. From: [Unable to install driver WN8200ND V2 (RTL8192EU)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003112/unable-to-install-driver-wn8200nd-v2-rtl8192eu))

I also tried to downgrade the kernel version (to try these drivers to run without success) to:

- 4.9.8
- 4.8.10 (ubuntu 18.04 didn't boot)
- 3.12.74 (ubuntu 18.04 didn't boot)

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way to activate TP-LINK WN8200ND**
**on UBUNTU 22.04 or Debian 11 (Debian without sudo), open terminal and =**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential dkms git
git clone https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux/
./install_wifi.sh
```

[image]