# TP-Link WiFi won't turn on

Tags: wireless, tp-link

I have installed a fresh Ubuntu on a desktop PC and connected my TP-Link (model: tl-wn8200nd) to it but it won't turn on.

I tried it on a Windows PC and it turned on just fine.

Please note that I'm completely new to Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drivers for TP-LINK TL-WN8200ND v2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078953/drivers-for-tp-link-tl-wn8200nd-v2)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a driver problem. Check out the manual for the linux installation: https://www.tp-link.com/support/download/tl-wn8200nd/