# Driver for wifi adapter TL-WN8200ND V2

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, kernel

Hello I'm new in the world of Linux, I need a driver for my wifi adapter, I tried several git repos but no one worked. I am using kernel 5.0.0 and Ubuntu 18.04.1. Please help me.

I tried the repo: https://github.com/luckynzm/tlwn8200nddriver and this threw me:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8192eu: 1.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.0.0-23-generic (x86_64)
```

on `sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0`

Also: https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver then:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8192eu: 1.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.0.0-23-generic (x86_64)
```

And also on `sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0;`

At the end tried this: https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de/issues/5#issuecomment-410850664 
And this didn't have any error but I think this was not my driver. :(

My pc info here https://gist.github.com/KFengF/c654d6a2a475172ab127d35c2b1a3652

Comment: You tagged 14.04? but mentioned 18.04.1?  (*your kernel implies an outdated 18.04.3 too*)  Please clarify, and what chipset is used?  ie. device recognition in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

Comment: Add `inxi -SMN -! 31 -y 80` output. Realtek RTL8192cu chipset? `lsmod | grep rtl8`? [This](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver) might help, already tried [the official](https://www.tp-link.com/en/download/TL-WN8200ND.html#Driver)?

Comment: @guiverc I read the docs. But I didn't find something useful. @PabloBianchi Ok I tried ````inxi -SMN -! 31 -y 80```` and the output is: `Network:   Card: Intel 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection driver: e1000e`

Comment: 82566DM-2 is an ethernet NIC and needs cables to work (it's not wireless). Providing output from commands such as `lshw` or `lspci` commands in link I provided (Device Recognition & Operation step 1) allow you to search online for clues, or when pasted into your question allow us to see what you've got & help. Replies of additional details should not be placed in comments

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `sudo dkms status`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: edited @chili555

Comment: Please try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003112/unable-to-install-driver-wn8200nd-v2-rtl8192eu

Comment: @chili555 already tried, didn't work, its git repos are published in this question already. :(

Comment: "ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8192eu: 1.0 not found" Please run the terminal command: `history` and tell us the three commands just before this. I suspect that one of them is faulty.

Comment: `````185  cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
  186  sudo dkms add .
  187  sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
````` just like the repo readme said @chili555

Comment: Is there any clue in the make.log found in /var/log/dkms? Please paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com